# ssh config multiple hostname to the same host

Tags: ssh

I config the following hostname in .ssh/config file

```
Host termux
    Hostname 192.168.43.1
    Port 8022
```

How could add more hostnames to the same host.

```
Host termux
    Hostname 192.168.43.1, 192.168.43. 12, 192.168.43.5
    Port 8022
```

Comment: How would it know which host to connect to when you do `ssh termux`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have a use case where I have N paths(diff hostnames and jumps) to get to the one host. 2 are quite usual: via jump-host(external) and via IP/DNS internal. It would be a case of trial and error. Btw: I do not want this to be made possible. I am very happy with seeing my config entries as "paths" not "hosts". Bit of a misnomer though....

Comment: For the benefit of the asker:  Put all the IPs into `/etc/hosts` under the same name.  Then use this name in `ssh_config` as the `Hostname`.  `ssh` then will try all of the given IPs and take the first IP it is able to connect to.  And BTW, **this is not a software nor hardware question**, this is a general computing question on how to properly use OS features.  Apparenty most people **do not know their OS features** (which `ssh` is able to use).  Yes, I mean you, the closers!

Comment: Nobody understood the question apparently.  Anwer are - remove Hostname and replace "termux" in Host section to "Host 192.168.43.*" or "Host 192.168.43.1 192.168.43. 12 192.168.43.5"

Comment: relevant topic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61655/multiple-similar-entries-in-ssh-config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Mad Physicist made a good point. You can't actually add more than one hostname to the same host. You could try, but it would just use the first one anyways.

You only have one option that I can think of. If you want to say what kind of functionality you want out of this, I may be able to give a better answer.

Instead of doing it the way you did in the example, you could make each hostname correspond to a different host. Maybe with numbering. Such as termux1, termux2, etc.

Comment: For every quesstion there is at least one answer which is absolutely straight forward, is easy to understand, makes perfect sense to all readers and is easy to follow, **but is completely wrong!**  This here is one of them. **SSH already supports multiple IPs for one host**.  I would answer if I could.  For starters:  Use a name and add the IPs (all of them) to `/etc/hosts`.  Voila, the name in ssh_config refers to that hostname which refers to multiple IPs and SSH tries all of them in sequence.

Comment: @Tino what you are claiming does not work for me. I am using OpenSSH version 7.6, and specifying multiple `HostName` just doesn't work (the second IP gets ignored). And putting everything in one line just throws the error `garbage at end of line`. What version are you using?

Comment: @User9123, you don't seem to be reading Tino's explanation. It does not say to add multiple Hostname entries or  put multiple IPs on one line. Please carefully read the comment on the original question.

Comment: My bad, I misread Tino's explanation. Modifying `/etc/hosts` is not specific to ssh, though, and cannot be modified without being root.

Comment: TIno's comment doesn't work on Android unless you want to root it. And a lot of people don't want to do that because it compromises security and prohibits many popular apps from working. I would also say that its misleading to state that "ssh already supports multiple IPs for one host" because what is being described here is not a behavior of SSH, but is a behavior of the operating system. (Please correct me if I'm wrong--that's just my impression of what's actually happening here).

Comment: @Tino Can you please provide a link to some documentation?